# What does SVO stand for?

Tags: acronyms

A newbie user question about acronym used today: "SVO." I'm puzzled as to what it could be. What is SVO pray tell? something verb order?

Comment: Hello, Shadow maker. ELU is aimed at English linguists, and SVO is a very basic initialism used in the relevant metalanguage. It's also easily researchable. Let-me-google-that-for-you answers aren't what ELU is about.

Comment: Thank you -- I had already realized the simplicity of my question after I submitted it. This site isn't exactly intuitive and a list of acronyms would be helpful. For me, linguistics is an interest, not a specialty. I am a writer with many questions, but few answers.

Comment: I hope you've read the advice at the Help Center? (Though admittedly, not all questions are as simplistic as they might first appear. There have been arguments over the exact meaning of 'word', 'sentence', 'complement', 'preposition' ... which I'm fairly sure have never been resolved.) (But _not_ 'SVO'.)

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking about [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/404103/svo-rule-exception), I had the same question, and did a search. :)

In this case, it stands for **Subject-Verb-Object**.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject%E2%80%93verb%E2%80%93object):

> In linguistic typology, subject–verb–object (SVO) is a sentence structure where the subject comes first, the verb second, and the object third. Languages may be classified according to the dominant sequence of these elements. The label is often used for ergative languages which do not have subjects, but have an agent–verb–object order.
>
> SVO is the second most common order by number of known languages, after SOV. Together, SVO and SOV account for more than 75% of the world's languages.[3] It is also the most common order developed in Creole languages, suggesting that it may be somehow more initially 'obvious' to human psychology.[4]

Comment: Thank you, your answer is helpful, informative, and on point. It's nice to have a full explanation, since there is more to it than simply what the letters in the acronym stand for. At least I learned something.

Comment: It's policy not to answer the really simple questions, but rather to help when people have already done research and hit a dead end. Accordingly, I have been downvoted for answering your question. Such is life, and I'm glad this was helpful.